# How to schedule tcpdump to run for a specific period of time?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

Each time, when I manually run `tcpdump`, I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it. Now I want to schedule my `tcpdump` with cronjob and I only need it to run for 1 and half hours. Without manually running <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or kill command, how can it be stopped automatically? Here is the command I am testing:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'port 8080' -w  myfile
```

I can schedule another cronjob  to kill the `tcpdump` process, but it seems not a good idea.

Comment: Either of the answers for tcpdump; a solution that works for any program (unless they fiddle with SIGALRM)is the sigalarm program from http://www.superscript.com/signal/index.html

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can combine `-G {sec}` (rotate dump files every x seconds) and `-W {count}` (limit # of dump files) to get what you want:

```
tcpdump -G 15 -W 1 -w myfile -i eth0 'port 8080'
```

would run for 15 seconds and then stop. Turn 1.5 hours into seconds and it should work.

Comment: Note: this trick doesn't work if you're not receiving any traffic.

Comment: Yeah, tcpdump won't rotate, close or otherwise do anything until it gets a packet.

Comment: Use: `-w myfile-%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S`.
With `-w myfile`, tcpdump will keep overwriting the same file after specified number of seconds. You must provide a file name with time format specified by `strftime` in order to avoid overwriting.

Comment: For me, with tcpdump 4.5.1, this works, but it suppresses the `N packets captured` / `N packets received by filter` / `N packets dropped by kernel` message printed on exist following an interrupt.

Answer (score 90):

you could use timeout

```
timeout 5400 tcpdump -i eth0 'port 8080' -w myfile
```

Comment: this looks simpler and more efficient.

Comment: `timeout 90m` is easier on the eyes.

Comment: This one's safer since `tcpdump -G` will run indefinitely if there's no traffic vie that interface in question.

Answer (score 24):

You could do it like this:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'port 8080' -w  myfile & 
pid=$!
sleep 1.5h
kill $pid
```

Comment: If you have a single instance of tcpdump, you can use `pkill tcpdump`

Answer (score 5):

The approach that worked best for me on Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo -i
crontab -e
```

and then add the line

```
30 17 * * * /usr/sbin/tcpdump -G 12600 -W 1 -s 3000 -w /home/ubuntu/capture-file.pcap port 5060 or portrange 10000-35000
```

Notes

- -G flag indicate number of second for dump to run, this example runs daily from 5:30 PM to 9:00 PM
- -W is the number of iterations tcpdump will execute
- Cron job will not be added until you save and exit the file
- This example is for capturing packets of an Asterisk phone server

Answer (score -7):

You can use

```
watch tcpdump -i eth0 'port 8080' -w  myfile
```

This will run every 2 seconds.