# How can I run tcpdump command with a script?

Tags: shell, cron, tcpdump

Im tired of trying to find a answer to this.
I got 2 scripts that are in crontab -e command.

START_TCPDUMP.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
tcpdump -i any port 3306 -s 65535 -x -nn -q -tttt> /etc/openvpn/logs/tcpdump_3306_"$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p")".out
```

STOP_TCPDUMP.sh

```
PID=$(/usr/bin/ps -ef | grep tcpdump | grep -v grep | grep -v ".sh" | awk '{print $2}')
/usr/bin/kill -9 $PID
```

CRONTAB -E

```
*/1 * * * * /etc/openvpn/script/STOP_TCPDUMP.sh
*/1 * * * * /etc/openvpn/script/START_TCPDUMP.sh
```

I already tryied to change and put start at first line but its all the same.

My output on directory every 1 min its:

```
/etc/openvpn/logs/tcpdump_3306_2020_01_29_12_22_PM.out (empty: 0kb)
```

The problem is that files are empty I already tried so much things and its always empty.
How can I figure this out?

Also If I run: ps -e | grep tcpdump I get 0 results.
But If I run: grep | tcpdump I saw the command running and showing me all the tracked packages..

I just want it to run like 3h and then stop, save the file and then start a new one.

The once per minute schedule is merely for debugging.

Comment: How do you expect it to produce any output when you have another job which is killing it pretty much instantly? A much better approach would be to use `pkill` anyway, you have the usual 5-6 bugs in your reimplementation.

Comment: How should It be then? Can you do that for me?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish. Why are you killing the job immediately? Do you not have the `pkill` utility, or at least `pgrep`?

Comment: I just want it to run like 3h and then stop, save the file and then start a new one

Comment: If you want it to run for one minute, you can use `fuser -k` on the file from the previous minute. If you have GNU `date` it should be easy to get the previous minute with `-d "1 minute ago"`; if not, this is slightly more challenging (try Awk, Perl, or Python, maybe).

Comment: If you want 3 hours, why do you run it every minute?

Comment: That was just for test.. and try to figure it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to schedule tcpdump to run for a specific time of period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731643/how-to-schedule-tcpdump-to-run-for-a-specific-time-of-period)

Answer (score 1):

The code to `kill` every running `tcpdump` process on the system is deeply problematic. You want to kill only the ones started by your `cron` job. Never use `kill -9` routinely; it should be used only in extreme circumstances.

The multiple [useless `grep`s](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) are also a bad smell, and seem extremely brittle. But let's simply get rid of that code.

My suggestion would be to have a single script which kills any previous instance and starts a new one.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
logdir=/etc/openvpn/logs
exec >> "$logdir/cron.log" 2>&1

fmt="%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p"
old=$(date -d "3 hours ago" +"$fmt")
new=$(date +"$fmt")

fuser -s -k -15 "$logdir/tcpdump_3306_$old.out"

tcpdump -i any port 3306 -s 65535 -x -nn -q -tttt>"$logdir/tcpdump_3306_$new.out"
```

This takes care to redirect all messages to a separate log file (otherwise `cron` will send you mail with the output) and to only kill processes which are attached to the previous instance of the `tcpdump` output file. (For testing maybe specify `"$logdir"/tcpdump*.out` or even `"$logdir"/*` to be really sure you get a clean slate.) The default signal of `fuser` is `-9`; if you really need that, just take out the `-15`.

`fuser` should be reasonably portable; `date` is more finicky, and won't have a `-d` option on many non-Linux platforms. You can always install GNU Coreutils, or switch to a simple Perl or Python script for the timestamp calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out!

I changed my method. I create a screen at crontab and it will run 24 hours per 7 days a week. Then I just enter file, save the info then clear the file and it will run automatically.

**crontab -e**

```
@reboot screen -dmS bTCP; sleep 5; screen -S bTCP -X stuff 'tcpdump -i any port 22 -s 65535 -x -nn -q -tttt> /path/to/logs/NAME.out\n'
*/2 * * * * /path/to/logs/24-pt-query.sh
```

The **24-pt-query** file its a python script to take the information, save it in a new file and then truncate it.

And it will repeat each 2 minute (debugging).